# Varnish: how to cache a URL with parameters - need to strip multiple parameters but not all

Tags: varnish

I'm testing a revised Varnish config and I need to see if certain URLs are hitting the cache or not. It seems not to like multiple parameters.

The Varnish config change is to not treat URLs with certain parameters as unique content. E.g.

```
/news/tech
/news/tech?itq=1001
/news/tech?itq=1002&ito=3553
```

should all be equivalent.

**Scenario 1**

Requesting a page that hasn't been cached yet:

```
curl -I 'http://example.com/news/tech'
```

Result:

```
X-Varnish-Cache: MISS
```

Sending the same request a second time gives this result:

```
X-Varnish-Cache: HIT
```

**Scenario 2**

Requesting the above URL again, but with a parameter:

```
curl -I 'http://example.com/news/tech?itq=1001'
```

That is one of the parameters to not treat as unique content.

Result:

```
X-Varnish-Cache: HIT
```

**Scenario 3**

Requesting with a second parameter:

```
curl -I 'http://example.com/news/tech?itq=1001&ito=3553'
```

Response:

```
X-Varnish-Cache: MISS
```

It seems like the Varnish config works for ? but not for &

Here's the relevant line in my Varnish config:

```
  set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "([\?|\&])+(utm_campaign|utm_content|utm_medium|utm_source|utm_term|ITO|et_cid|et_rid|qs|itq|ito|itx\[idio\])=[^&\s]*&?", "\1");
```

I guess this is only running once, so it won't strip out multiple parameters. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation, I found a way to do this.

```
# Strip out query parameters that do not affect the page content
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "([\?|\&])+(utm_campaign|utm_content|utm_medium|utm_source|utm_term|ITO|et_cid|et_rid|qs|itq|ito|itx\[idio\])=[^&\s]+", "\1");
# Get rid of trailing & or ?
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "[\?|&]+$", "");
# Replace ?&
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "(\?\&)", "\?");
```

The 2nd and 3rd commands are just cleanup. But this does seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation @thirtyish gives issues when it is used with combination of additional get parameters.

e.g. `?utm_campaign=1&utm_source=2&my_add_parameter=3` is not working.

If we change the order to `?my_add_parameter=3=utm_campaign=1&utm_source=2` is working.
And by not working I mean it generates multiple `&` signs in the url query.

I update the regex to fix that.

```
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "[\?\&](utm_\w+|hsa_\w+|gclid|fbclid|pc)=[^&\s]+", "");
# trailing & or ?
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "[\?|&]+$", "");
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "(\?\&)|(\&)", "\?");
```